# Windows phone 8.1 Geo Location does not work unless the phone resides in the geo-location for atleast 2 to 3 seconds

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating a windows Phone 8.1 application with the Geo Location. The code works, well pretty much, the one thing that I have noticed in the simulator, if the phone does not reside in the Geo-Fenced area for a 2 .. 3 .. seconds the background code does not fire even though I create my dwell time with no parameters.

```
        MonitoredGeofenceStates mask = 0;
        mask |= MonitoredGeofenceStates.Entered;

        var geocircle = new Geocircle(position, 100);
        gFence = new Geofence(ID, geocircle, mask, false);
```

I found the following blog but it was not that useful
http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/02/25/testing-and-debugging-your-geofencing-apps/

How often does a phone or device check if its in a Geo fenced area? I would like to tell my users for their geo-fence to be active they must reside in the geo-fenced area for a minimum of x seconds...

Comment: Have you tried the Geofence constructor that allows you to specify Dwell Time: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263717.aspx

Comment: Yes, this is where I started, but to keep the sample simple I do not have dwell time.I am receiving the same results with including a dwell time of 0 and not including a dwell time at all.

Comment: "When creating geofences that use a dwell time, the time span must be greater than 0." Have you tried with 1 second? Anyway, I too found the geofences in the new WP8.1 to be very unreliable ....

Comment: I will try 1 second... when I get home tonight. Thank you for confirming my issue that I am not doing something wrong.

Comment: I changed the value to 1 second and the results are the same. It seems the device needs to be in the geo location for a minimum of 10 seconds which requires a Geo Beacon area of 400 Meters if the car is traveling at 64 km so a radius of 200 Meters is required.